# Camel-JCFIS large file 94MB fails

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am copying file using camel-jcifs. When the files are large it started failing. Below are the options I am passing

smb://server/Reports?bufferSize=4280&delay=60000&delete=true&include=.*.xls&localWorkDirectory=/tmp&moveFailed=.failed&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=60000&readLockLoggingLevel=WARN&readLockMinLength=0&readLockTimeout=3600000

Error message :

Caused by: jcifs.smb.SmbException: Transport1 timedout waiting for response to SmbComWriteAndX[command=SMB_COM_WRITE_ANDX

Any help is much appreciated.